# No location in metadata of place when in plane?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, geolocation, metadata

I have noticed when taking photos in airplane, the phone has no metadata. I don’t know why but is there a app which can save metadata of where the plane is passing like offline google maps for aeroplane and when taken a photo, save the metadata?

I have iPhone 14 Pro Max.

Comment: It has no metadata whatsoever?  There's no EXIF data about the camera, focal length, etc.?  I can understand missing location data, but camera data being missing seems odd.

Comment: What kind of metadata do you miss?

Comment: I have location data (possibly lucky my phone could see GPS), and all the rest, with airplane mode on, when taking photos with an iPhone from a plane window. You'll need to provide some more info, what camera / phone / camera app?

Comment: @allan I even don‘t understand lack of location data: GPS is receive-only so airplane mode shouldn‘t matter, and the few shots I just took in airplane mode contain location data as expected.

Comment: In some versions of IOS, turning on airplane mode turned off ALL radios, and the only way to restore GPS was to turn on WiFi.  But also (as Alan's answer amplifies), I noticed that in most planes, I could get GPS by placing my iPhone against the window but not when it was in my lap or shirt pocket.

Comment: @WGroleau How would u know if u got GPS status on iPhons?

Comment: My tracker app tells me the accuracy or "unable to get a fix"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Your device uses A-GPS

The problem is that [A-GPS](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/24218/assisted-gps-a-gps) (Augmented/Assisted GPS) requires a reliable signal from four satellites *and* the cellphone location data.  All iPhones (from at least the 3G) use A-GPS.

GPS itself requires data from four (4) GPS satellites to triangulate your position.  While triangulation implies three (3) (and technically you only need three if this were a 2D world) the fourth it to determine altitude.  The cellular "assistance" is to speed in location services startup and for providing a generalized location to supplement the data provided by GPS.  See [Improve GPS accuracy by disabling cellular data](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/334226/119271)

#### GPS signals are weak

Unfortunately, GPS signals are easily blocked by native obstructions like trees, hills, and mountains. They are also blocked by man-made obstacles like building structures, walls, roofs and even the aluminum skin of the tube hurtling  through the air.  Surprisingly, [airplane fuselages block a lot of the GPS signals](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8861)

The following is from an [ieee.org article about threats to GPS](https://spectrum.ieee.org/faa-files-reveal-a-surprising-threat-to-airline-safety-the-us-militarys-gps-tests#toggle-gdpr).  To put this into context, a study was commissioned to investigate loss of GPS signal by both military and civilian aircraft.  A major component was GPS testing by the military.  However, they also noted that the GPS signal was already subject to both natural and man-made  interference.

> GPS interference can be affected by the terrain, aircraft altitude and attitude, direction of flight, angle to and distance from the center of the interference, equipment aboard the plane, and many other factors, concluded the task group, which included representatives of the FAA, airlines, pilots, aircraft manufacturers, and the U.S. military.

#### What about the airplane's GPS?

If the GPS signal inside the plane is so weak, then how does the airplane's own GPS continue to function?

**The GPS antenna is located on the top of the aircraft**

- [GPS Antenna Installation Guidelines](https://www.dallasavionics.com/comant/ci429-200_install.pdf)
- [How many antennae are there on a typical small aircraft, and how are they connected to the avionics?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/44330) (Aviation Stack Exchange)

Because this GPS antenna is *outside* of the airplane, it has a clean, unobstructed signal from which to receive GPS data.  Even with this, it's still subject to the interferences as described above.  The tiny chip in your phone doesn't stand a chance being inside the phone that's inside the plane.

#### TL;DR

You're missing the location EXIF data from your photo because it simply wasn't available at that particular moment the image was captured due to GPS signals not getting through to your phone.

Comment: This is great answer. Thank u so much for the descriptive answer